# How to match two csv files columns to obtain a new file

Tags: awk, csv

I have two csv files:

first file:

```
"ACCOUNT_CODE","FK_CLIENT_CODE","ENVIRONMENT","HHID"  
"13445319","V8571485","SAT","IT00000000000005676070"  
"10580347","V6559553","SAT","IT00000000000003952833"   
"22124274","V11943127","DTT","IT00000000000008535651"   
"11896497","V7524852","SAT","IT00000000000005652668"
```

second file:

```
IT00000000000005676070   
IT00000000000000060265           
IT00000000000008535651   
IT00000000000000060267
```

Both files have millions of lines.
I want to match the values of the first file (values of the last column called HHID) with the values of the second file. The values are not sorted and I want that for each HHID the search is performed in the whole second file.

If the value is not found, a third file will be created with values not present in the second file. Example new file:

third file:

```
"ACCOUNT_CODE","FK_CLIENT_CODE","ENVIRONMENT","HHID" 
"10580347","V6559553","SAT","IT00000000000003952833"       
"11896497","V7524852","SAT","IT00000000000005652668"
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($8 in a)' file2 FS='"' file1
"ACCOUNT_CODE","FK_CLIENT_CODE","ENVIRONMENT","HHID"
"10580347","V6559553","SAT","IT00000000000003952833"
"11896497","V7524852","SAT","IT00000000000005652668"
```

Comment: Very very useful :D